# Testing iOS Applications with latest Appium Tool

Tags: ios, unit-testing, automated-tests, appium, ios-ui-automation

**I need to test iOS Application. I have installed appium on Mac.**

I have installed below Tools:

- 1) XCODE
- 2) JDK
- 3) Commmand Line Tools
- 4) Appium

I am getting following errors while running appium server for testing sample iOS application.
[image]

[image]

[image]

**Anybody tell me the steps to how to perform iOS Application Testing Using Latest Appium Tool?**

Must appreciate for any better Suggestions for testing iOS Applications

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with iOS 9.3 appium is using **XCUITest** for testing iOS apps.

So you need to read [official documentation](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver) about required setup.

And there is another doc about setup for [real device execution](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md).

Note: for Xcode 9.1 you have to use Appium server **1.7.2-beta** and above

Comment: Since you have xcode 9.1, you need to use Appium 1.7.2-beta: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9534